# how to find empty values in array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on to create a comparison of college i  almost completed It but now i want find the empty values and put a strike instead of empty column i know i can do this using if statements  what i am seeking is there a better way other than using nested if else or multiple if

controller has a function to select value

```
public function test()
    {
        $insId  = "INS20160738";
        $course = "B.Tech Electronics & Communication Engineering";
        $this->load->model('comparisonModel');
            $resFirst   = $this->comparisonModel->selFirst($insId,$course);
            foreach ($resFirst as $key => $value) {
                echo '<h6> name:</h6><p>'.$value['course_name'].'</p><h6>Duration:</h6>'.$value['duration'].'
                     <h6>eligiblity:</h6><p>'.$value['eligibility'].'</p><h6>recognition:</h6><p>'.$value['recognition'].'</p><h6>Affiliation:</h6>'.$value['affiliation'].'
                     <h6>Certification:</h6>'.$value['certificate'].'<h6>Category:</h6>'.$value['category'].'<h6>Type:</h6>'.$value['type'].'<h6>Category:</h6>'.$value['school_batch'].'';
            }
    }
```

model for the selecting is

```
public function selFirst($insId,$course)
  {
    $stmt='SELECT * FROM `institute-course` WHERE `institute-id`=  '.$this->db->escape($insId).' AND `course_name`='.$this->db->escape($course);
    $res=$this->db->query($stmt);
    return $res->result_array();
  }
```

i get result like this

```
name:

B.Tech Electronics & Communication Engineering

Duration:

eligiblity:

plus two

recognition:

Affiliation:

A P J Abdul Kalam Technological University
Certification:

B.Tech in Electronics & Communication Engineering
Category:

under graduate
Type:

college
Category:
```

what i searching is there a better way to get result like this

```
name:

B.Tech Electronics & Communication Engineering

Duration: this field is Empty or put a strike 

eligiblity:

plus two

recognition:this field is empty

Affiliation:

A P J Abdul Kalam Technological University
Certification:

B.Tech in Electronics & Communication Engineering
Category:

under graduate
Type:This Is filed Is empty
college
Category: this field is empty
```

with out using multiple if else statements

thanks in advance

Comment: why you format code inside controller. you can do it on View easily

Comment: so that no php code inside view

Comment: Check my answer. Its works on controller. if you need to show them in view pass them and chnage foreach variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In foreach loop try this (**controller**)

```
foreach ($resFirst as $value) 
{
?>
    <h6> name:</h6>
        <p> <?= (empty($value['course_name'])) ? 'this field is empty' : $value['course_name'] ; ?> </p>
    <h6> Duration:</h6>
        <p> <?= (empty($value['duration'])) ? 'this field is empty' : $value['duration'] ;?> </p>
    <h6> eligiblity:</h6>
        <p> <?= (empty($value['eligiblity'])) ? 'this field is empty' : $value['eligiblity'] ;?> </p>
    <h6> recognition:</h6>
        <p> <?= (empty($value['recognition'])) ? 'this field is empty' : $value['recognition'] ;?> </p>
    <h6> Affiliation:</h6>
        <p> <?= (empty($value['affiliation'])) ? 'this field is empty' : $value['affiliation'] ; ?> </p>
    <h6> Certification:</h6>
        <p> <?= (empty($value['certificate'])) ? 'this field is empty' : $value['certificate'] ; ?> </p>
    <h6> Category:</h6>
        <p> <?= (empty($value['category'])) ? 'this field is empty' : $value['category'] ; ?> </p>
    <h6> Type:</h6>
        <p> <?= (empty($value['type'])) ? 'this field is empty' : $value['type'] ; ?> </p>
    <h6> Category:</h6>
        <p> <?= (empty($value['school_batch'])) ? 'this field is empty' : $value['school_batch'] ; ?> </p>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test if the value is empty

```
if (empty($value['type'])) {
    $value['type'] = 'This field is empty';
}
```

Or if the value is NULL in the database, you can specify it in the `select` - clause:

```
SELECT *, IFNULL(type, 'This field is empty') ...
```